# Происхождение гриновских названий

Tags: этимология, литература

Ясно, что города, описанные Грином, вымышленные, хоть, насколько я знаю, у них есть реальные прототипы, например, Балаклава или Феодосия. Но, интересно, названия Лисс и Зурбаган — просто случайное сочетание букв или он брал за основу какие-то реальные названия?

Answer (score 1):

Это не мой ответ. Просто привожу ссылку на сайт с "Картой Гринландии"  http://grinlandia.narod.ru/map/map.htm
Но там еще много интересного по теме.

Comment: И еще очень красивая статья на эту же тему.http://www.proza.ru/2012/06/25/447

Answer (score 0):

Не читал пока материалы по ссылкам, будут возможность - прочитаю, сравним.
Пока навскидку.
Лисс - усеченное Лиссабон.
Зурбаган - образование по типу Исфахань, каких много в Иране и Турции.

При этом кроме названия эти города ничего с гриновскими не связывает.
Поэтому гораздо интересенее найти прообразы самих городов...
Мне Зурбаган опредленно напоминает Керчь, Лисс - Феодосию. И все сразу - Одессу, но это уже потому, что она напоминает все южные портовые города.

Comment: Мне приходилось в юном ворасте читать,что Лисс или Зурбаган напоминают кому-то Севастополь,Гель-Гью - Керчь или Феодосию,кто-то видит в гриновских пейзажах Ялту или Одессу.Я прочел всего Грина, до которого мог дотянуться.Включая собрание сочинений,вышедшее в 60-х.И считаю - все его городские пейзажи абсолютно вымышлены и совершенно далеки от реальных черноморских портовых городов.Но он их видел, они существовали в его уникальном воображении со всеми подробностями.И они прекрасны.

Comment: Понимаете, "абсолютно вымышленных" городов (и вообще чего бы то ни было) не бывает. Всегда автор базируется на каких-то воспоминаниях, идеях, ассоциациях...

В свое время я тоже объездил все тогда еще советское Черноморское побережье вдоль и поперек, и должен сказать, что приморские города похожи.
Хотя признаться, в моем понимании Крым всегда уступал Кавказу, особенно красавцу Батуму... Вот, кстати, совсем, уж не гриновский город...
Каждому у Грина видится что-то свое, поэтому и такие разбросы во мнениях. И надо ещё учитывать, что между нами и Грином - минимум полвека...